# How to test if processes are using files in directory

Tags: shell-script, shell, lsof

I'm trying to use lsof in an IF statement to tar a directory ONLY if other programs are NOT using files within the directory. I can get this info at a shell prompt with

```
lsof +d /mydir/
```

If it doesn't return any output, I know the directory is not in use. How do I format that into a conditional statement so that

```
if (lsof returns anything) then
  echo "$folder in use"
else
  tar $folder
```

Thanks

Comment: are you okay with files being used in the directory any time after lsof makes whatever call to obtain that info, between the various shell code involved, and when tar is running but has not yet reached a particular now open file?

Comment: `lsof +d ...` doesn't check for open files recursively; perhaps you meant `+D`?  But `tar` will give a warning in any case if something changes on the files it's compressing while it's running.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297251/135943

Comment: I chose +d because I know there will not be any subdirs within the folder I examine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the characters in the answer, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="$(lsof +d "${folder}")"

if [[ "${#a}" -gt 0 ]] then
    echo "${folder} in use"
else
    tar "${folder}"
fi
```

Comment: This worked, but I wonder if you can explain your use of the "${#a}"  --specifically, what does the # do?

Comment: The # means: `the length of` (in characters). So `"${#a}"` is the number of characters in the variable `$a`, What you asked for. @Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can try counting the number of lines in the output. I get one header-row of column names and then one additional result-row for each active process, e.g.:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    1002 debian  cwd    DIR  254,4     4096 393217 .
lsof    1592 debian  cwd    DIR  254,4     4096 393217 .
lsof    1593 debian  cwd    DIR  254,4     4096 393217 .
```

When I use the `wc -l` command to count the number of lines it also counts the trailing newline. This means that `wc -l` should count 2 lines of output when there are no active processes. So something like this should work:

```bsh
if [[ $(lsof +d "${folder}" | wc -l) -gt 2 ]]; then
  echo "${folder} in use"
else
  tar "${folder}"
fi
```

It also looks like you might want to use the `lsof +D` invocation (capital 'D' instead of lower-case 'd') to perform a recursive, full-descent search of the directory.